# Windows Server 2008R2 WDS using MDT added applications but they arent installing

Tags: deployment, windows, wds, packaging, mdt

Not important information:
I've a MDT server 2010 setup on a Windows 2008 R2 server
I've configured DHCP for PXE and its working fine
I've a custom Scheduled task configured to set my keyboard, display and join the domain correctly
I've the CAB files added for all the different laptops and they deploy
The scheduled task asks For the computer name and then the applications I've added.
The image deploys the machine is joined to the domain it hits my WSUS server and does the updates.
All drivers are installed correctly from the CAB files (I love Dell)

Important bit:

The scheduled task hits the application installation piece. It installs Malware bytes, WinRAR and Keepass no problem. Mentions the other applications within the deployment screen which I've added like Visio, 7 Zip, Winscp, 3CXPhone. But they aren't installed. I've followed the silent install instructions from http://www.itninja.com but I'm getting no errors in the log file.

Can someone point me in the right direction for troubleshooting the problem as I can't even find the log file to check why they have not installed.

Also if someone has a step by step guide on how to add in Office from O365 in as an application I'd really appreciate it. Right now the only way I can see of doing it is installing it directly to the image. which I don't want to do. I want it as an application I can select.

Thank you!

David

Answer (score 0):

Are you copying the log files back to the deployment share for later review? This is acheived by setting the following variable:

`SLShare=\\ServerName\DeploymentShare$\Logs`

and for real-time logging:

`SLShareDynamicLogging=\\ServerName\DeploymentShare$\Logs`

I recommend using both. Now that you have the logs to review you can check ZTIApplications.log using CMTrace.exe from the SCCM tools. In this log you can verify that the 1) the installation started 2) the return code. The return code is nice but seldom gives you the detail needed to troubleshoot. In the command to install the application you should specify log options which is VERY dependent on the installer type. Finally run the installation outside of MDT using the exact same conditions (same user, mapped drives) to verify your installation command is valid.

PS: If installing 7-ZIP using the exe silently make sure the "/S" is a CAPITAL S. The Nullsoft installer is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I think the problem was the capital letters for the silent installs. I've also found log files in C:\windows\temp\ which are helpful